# How to emulate context menu key when there's none on keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Imagine a keyboard that lacks <kbd>Win</kbd> key. That's easy to emulate - you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. However, on the keyboard I have now, there's no "right mouse" key (or "context menu" key or whatever it might be called - it's usually placed close to <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and bears the sign of three horizontal bars or something).

I'm very used to pressing that key and not having it around slows me down (not to mention the annoyance aspect). How can I emulate it on this limited keyboard?

Comment: Do you have any keys on the keyboard you don't often use?

Comment: Why the downvote?!

Comment: @Keltari I beg to differ. When I'm in a window with a bunch of files, for instance, and mark one by pressing e.g. "a", it's very quick to press the key in question and then "s" to send the file to someone. I know a lot of people using it (none of whom is heavy on the rodent usage).

Comment: @nhinkle Sadly, no. It's this tiny, minimalistic and circumcised keyboard from Surface...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you're looking for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

EDIT: Some smaller keyboards require you to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in combination with <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> to use them. Most of the time you can 'function lock' with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> or change the default behavior of the F keys in the BIOS.

Comment: @ṧнʊß It works for me both on my laptop keyboard and the attached usb wireless keyboard.

Comment: @ṧнʊß: I use it all the time on keyboards that don't have menu keys...Although it doesn't work in EVERY context. For example, I can open a context menu on a webpage with the menu key or right-clicking, but not with Shift+F10. It works *almost* everywhere. Works within Windows Explorer. EDIT: Your F10 key might only work if you have your Fn key depressed depending on your laptop keyboard configuration.

Comment: Sorry forgot about 'fn'. +1 for the simple solution

Comment: @ṧнʊß Actually, the remark about Fn-key is important, because on the smallish keyboards, they're often in secondary use. I've activated them as primary key by CapsLocking them but I'll edit the reply to improve it from good to great.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was at a loss when the new system came without any.

Answer (score 2):

The button you're referring to is called the 'Menu key' btw.

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) to [remap](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) the menu key to another key on your keyboard (even without having the key on your keyboard).

I detest the Caps Lock key, so I would use that instead:

Install AHK, and create a notepad file, ending with `.ahk`, containing:

```
CapsLock::AppsKey
```

This triggers the menu key (`AppsKey`) when the caps lock button is pressed.

If you don't want to use the Caps Lock key, see [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm) for a list of keys AHK supports.

Comment: you fixed it.  appskey is correct

Comment: @Keltari Yeah - before, I had 'menu' in my head and typed that instead!

Answer (score 0):

I found using AutoHotKey with the following script seemed to work

```
<^>!m::AppsKey
return
```

mapping

```
AltGr + m
```

to the Context Menu / Apps Key / Menu Key

For some reason if I tried to use *just* the AltGr Key

```
<^>!
```

it didn't work, I needed to add another key and chose "m" as it's close and easy to hit in combo.

To have this mapping run automatically after a reboot :

- win + R
- type 
  shell:common startup
- Copy a shortcut to the AHK script
  and paste it in here
- might say you can't and do you want it on
  desktop
- If so say yes then cut and paste it from desktop to the
  startup folder

N.B. if other people use the machine and do NOT want the mapping, use

```
shell:startup
```

instead